# Android GridView setOnItemClickListener get TextView value

Tags: android, gridview

i need to get Category Id from a GridView item on Click but i don't know how to do it i can only get the position of item in the grid , 0 , 1 , 2 ... here is my code

My TextView in the XML

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/catid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />
```

my GridView :

```
    final GridView gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // start-media code could go in fragment or adapter
            Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                    ,"position: "+position
                    +" cat id :"+gridView.getAdapter().getItem(position)
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Category ID means..?

Comment: What is the value printed by toast for cat id:

Comment: @Mourad , For getting the answer better to answer these queries as well.

Comment: the cat id , is the position of item in the gridView  0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created customer adapter i.e. MyAdapter which may extend BaseAdapter.
There is a method in it called **getItemId**, you can get category id from there and you just need to set that value there.

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getCatId();
    }
```

Now you find your catId as id in below method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// here id will be your catId
}
```

if my answer helps, kindly upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
     {
         String data=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


     }});
```

data contains your clicked position's data. Do what ever you want to do with that.

Comment: 11-30 11:23:27.961: E/AndroidRuntime(14767): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gridexample.ui.Categories$Item cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Please add your adapter to the question

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
 {
     String data=((TextView)view).getText().toString();


 }});
```